# Что помешало parse() обработать форму?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Разбирая вот этот [туториал](http://www.nodebeginner.ru/#a-basic-http-server) (автор Manuel Kiessling), наткнулся на ошибку при выполнении финального примера; описание этой ошибки и действия, которые приводят к её устранению, описаны [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33672416/6053444).

Собственно, вопрос - почему эти действия решают проблему?

Суть проблемы вкратце: метод parse() модуля formidable не может распарсить форму, поля fields и files остаются undefined. Казалось бы, очевидно, что проблема должна крыться где-то в определении формы, раз она не парсится, однако решение заключается в изменении кода совершенно в другом месте — убрали обработчики событий с объекта request - так что для меня причинно-следственная связь так и осталась неочевидной. Хотелось бы разобраться, что именно не давало parse() отработать правильно.

Код формы (располагается в файле requestHandlers.js):

```
var body = '<html>' +
  '<head>' +
  '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />' +
  '</head>' +
  '<body>' +
  '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
  '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple">' +
  '<input type="submit" value="Upload File">' +
  '</form>' +
  '</body>' +
  '</html>';
```

Далее эта форма парсится таким образом:

```
function upload(response, request) {
   console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");

   var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
   console.log("about to parse");
   form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
     console.log("parsing done");

     /* Возможна ошибка в Windows: попытка переименования уже существующего файла */
     fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function(err) {
        if (err) {
         fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
         fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");
        }
     });

     response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
     response.write("received image:<br/>");
     response.write("<img src='/show' />");
     response.end();
   });
 }
```

Решение (файл server.js):

вместо вот этих строк

```
//      req.setEncoding("utf8");
//      req.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
//          postData += postDataChunk;
//      });
//      req.addListener("end", function() {
//          route(handle, pathname, res, req);
//      });
```

оставляем просто

```
route(handle, pathname, res, req);
```

Comment: лучше сразу показать кусок кода с проблемой

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: Надо полагать, запрос не генерирует ни событие 'data', ни событие 'end' (как это делает AJAX).

Comment: @YuriyPo тогда мы бы не попали в route (это маршрутизатор запросов), но мы попадаем в неё в том, и в другом случае, только в первом случае парсинг формы сначала надолго виснет, потом вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: Откуда известно, что вы в него попадаете, если "вылетает с ошибкой"?

Comment: Напишите перед route строчку `console.log('bla');`, и если это bla напечатается, то я не прав.

Comment: @YuriyPo не правы: "Received POST data chunk 
_bla_
About to route a request for /upload
Request handler 'upload' was called.
about to parse"

Comment: собственно, через route() там всё проходит, в т.ч. вызов parse(), иначе никак в эту точку не попасть

Comment: Модуль formidable запрашивает нативный модуль emitter и сам генерирует нужные события - это в его коде просто написано. Событие end там тоже генерится, и неоднократно. А у вас лишний слушатель прикручен к запросу (вернее, два). Что я могу сказать? Я облажался.

Comment: @YuriyPo На свежую голову я перечитал нужное место в туториале ещё раз, и, похоже, понял, где облажался _я_ )) Впрочем, по-прежнему до конца не понимаю смысла фразы "мы уже «поглотили» события data объекта request в сервере _(как? почему?)_, а следовательно, form.parse, которому так же надо поглощать эти события, не сможет получить больше данных (потому что Node.js не буферизирует данные)."

Comment: Ну модуль его "поглотил" - там это просто уже написано.

Comment: @YuriyPo спасибо за желание помочь, ваши комментарии натолкнули на нужные мысли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, я просто был невнимателен, и ответ на этот вопрос в туториале таки есть:

> ...Давайте полностью удалим всё, что касается postData в нашем сервере и
>   обработчиках запроса — он нам не нужен для обработки загрузки файла и,
>   мало того, — даже создает проблему: мы уже «поглотили» события data
>   объекта request в сервере, а следовательно, form.parse, которому так
>   же надо поглощать эти события, не сможет получить больше данных
>   (потому что Node.js не буферизирует данные).

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    route(handle, pathname, response, request);
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

что и требовалось.